# POSTing to session-validate.jsp not playing with WSO2 ELB

Tags: wso2

I came across an issue using WSO2 Stratos 1.6.0 when trying to browse the registry. The browser just hangs when clicking on Resources > Browse. Having a look at the network traffic I see an HTTP POST request to /carbon/admin/jsp/session-validate.jsp that doesn't complete.

I then started debugging the org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker (2.1.1-wsov1) in the WSO2ELB (2.0.2). I found that the code that writes the ACK to the response output stream is being skipped. This only appears to happen when POSTing to /carbon/admin/jsp/session-validate.jsp, when I hacked the /carbon/admin/js/main.js to perform a GET, everything worked fine.

So my question(s) being... is this a bug in main.js? is it a bug in ServerWorker in WSO2ELB? is there a special reason that the sessionAwareFunction in main.js uses POST as opposed to GET?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the transport ELB uses. Please use the latest release ELB http://wso2.com/products/elastic-load-balancer/